# External EXT4 Partition vanished. Ubuntu 14.08

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, ext4

I've had partitions disappear before and been able to rebuild and recover, this time its different.
I have a Seagate 200g drive that is a couple of years old and showing bad sectors. No problem, I recently bought a second drive a few months ago for backup. I would regularly back up but this time I decided to try to fix the bad drive so I made a backup to the newish drive called BAK, once done, all files were there and appeared working. I wrote zeros to the bad drive (on a seperate Windows computer) but it looks like physical damage, no problem I thought, my backup will now be the main drive!
I shutdown the Linux computer and installed the BAK drive into the computer and started up. Got the message unable to mount hdrive (old one) pressed skip and it booted up. Well you can imagine my horror when I opened the Bak drive to find nothing! Looked in DISKS and its no longer called BAK and looks like its been formatted? Two partitions, one 250g, the other 1.8tg. Ive only ever had one ext4 partition. Testdisk shows the drive but reports two partitions.
Anyone got any idea what happened and if its recoverable?
Much appreciated...

Comment: How did you back up the first drive?  Did you look in the 1.8G partition?

Comment: I formatted BAK as ext4 and did a successful drag and drop of the folders. Once complete I checked it and it looked ok. Nothing was done to the disk after that except shutdown then reboot with the drive installed internally. It now shows two partitions, one 250g and one 1.8 which is roughly representing the 250g free and 1,8 used. Neither DISKS nor testdisk show it as an ext4. I'm running extensive tests under testdisk. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: Sorry, the 1.8g partition has nothing, reported as free space

Comment: Did you format a partition on BAK or the disk itself?  If  the disk itself was formatted, try mounting it with the -o loopback to see if you see your files.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I have found it using testdisk. Run under Intel type but it reported an NTFS which the drive has never had but I found it under type None and Im hopefully saving the files off it now.
Really strange one, I have no idea what could have corrupted it in the first place? And it had to happen on my backup when the original drive was being wiped, I need to back up my back up :-)
Thanks again for your help!